# Recreate the /portals/community site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

We deleted the `domain.sharepoint.com/portals/community` Site Collection. How do we recreate it?

[image: We deleted the portals/community site.]

Answer (score 2):

### **SharePoint 2013 On Premise**

**Create a Community Site**

1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:

To create a site collection by using the Community Site template, you must be a member of the Farm Administrators group on the computer running the SharePoint Central Administration website or a service application administrator. If you are a service application administrator, you must also have permission to create site collections in the web application in which you create the Community Site.

2. In Central Administration, click Application Management, and then
   click **Create site collections**.
3. On the **Create Site Collection** page, in the **Web Application** section, ensure that the selected web application is the web application in which you want to create the Community Site. If it is not, expand the list, and then click **Change Web Application**. In the **Select Web Application** dialog box, select a different web application.
4. In the **Title and Description** section, type a title and description for the site collection.
5. In the **Web Site Address** section, select the URL where you want this site collection created.
6. In the **Template Selection** section, in the **Select experience version** list, select **2013**. Then, on the **Collaboration** tab, click **Community Site**.
7. In the **Primary Site Collection Administrator** section, and optionally
   in the **Secondary Site Collection Administrator** section, type an
   account in the format domain\username to specify an administrator
   for the site collection.
8. Optionally, in the **Quota Template** section, select a quota template.
9. Click **OK**.
10. **Verification:** After the site collection is created successfully,
        click the link to open the Community Site.

Reference:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219543.aspx

### **For Office 365**

1. Go to > **Admin** > **Service settings** > **Sites** > **Create site collection**.
2. In **Title**, enter the name of your community. This title will appear
   on the community home page and in the global navigation across the
   top of the page. If you choose to include a link to the community on
   the parent site Quick Launch or global navigation bar, this title
   will be displayed.
3. In **Select a language**, choose the primary language for the site. User
   interface text, including menu names and titles, will be displayed
   in the language you choose.
4. In **Select a template**, choose **Community Site**.
5. In **Time Zone**, your current zone is detected and displayed by
   default. Change it if necessary.
6. In **Administrator**, enter the name of the person or persons who will
   administer the community site. These names (separated by commas)
   must already exist in the company address list.
7. In **Storage Quota**, enter the amount of storage space on the server to
   dedicate to this site collection.
8. In **Server Resource Quota**, enter the amount of server resources to
   dedicate to this site collection. The default value is 300.

Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-community-8b6bb936-7ebc-4e60-b8ab-2d4897499af9

Comment: Does this create the site at the /portals/community URL? Usually, when we follow your process, we can only choose between the /teams and /sites URLS and do not have the /portals option available.